Is the fixed point index bounded?
I am working with the notion of fixed point index presented in the book "The Lefschetz fixed point theorem" of Robert Brown (MR283793, Zbl 0216.19601) and I would like to know if given any fixed compact ANR $X$ and map $f:X\to X$ the fixed point index is bounded. In other words, if given $X$ and $f$, there exists a bound $M$ such that
$$
|\operatorname{\mathit{i}}(X,f,U)|<M
$$ for all admissible open sets $U$ of $X$.
Thank you in advance
Edit. I mean any of the two equivalent definitions of the index given in that book, the axiomatic one or the other more explicit: the index $i(X,f,U)$ satisfies $k^\ast\circ (j^{-1})^\ast\circ d^\ast(\alpha)=i(X,f,U)\beta$, with $\alpha,\beta$ adecuate generators of $H^m(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{R}^m\setminus\{0\})$ and $H^m(S^m)$; $j:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow S^m$ the inclusion, $d=i-fr:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ for a specific retraction $r:V\rightarrow U$ and $k^\ast:H^m(S^m,S^m\setminus F)\rightarrow H^m(S^m)$ is the connecting homomorphism, where $F$ is the set of fixed points of $f$ on $U$. Details in the picture.

Just to be clear, do you have a reason for wanting to know about the fixed point index in this level of generality?   Is the original Lefschetz fixed point theorem insufficient for a particular application?

Yes, the original Lefschetz fixed point theorem is insufficient. I need explicitly the index to be bounded, but any partial result under some additional hypothesis could be also helpful. An example of this kind of hyphotesis (the problem is that it is too strong) is to require the index to be always positive.

So you need it in the full generality of ANRs, i.e. absolutely no restriction on your spaces?

@Ryan Budney My spaces are finite simplicial complexes, but any hint on other spaces will be appreciated.

Could you write a complete statement of the theorem down?  Apologies I can't find a copy of the book on-line, at least, not one I can access from home.   I think for simplicial complexes application of the theorem should be fairly straightforward i.e. likely finding the sets U will be direct.  Specifically, what exactly is $i(X, f, U)$?

@Ryan Budney I don't know what theorem you are refering to. I have uploaded the definition of the index as an image. The other definition is the one given by axioms, that is, the index is a map from the admissible triples (that is (X,f,U) where f does not have fixed points on the border of U) to the integers that satisfies: 1/Localization: if $g=f$ on $cl(U)$ then $i(X,f,U)=i(X,g,U)$. 2/ Homotopy Axiom (with a homotopy without fixed points on the closure of the open set). 3/ Additivity axiom. 4/ Normalization: $i(X,f,X)$ is the Lefschetz number. 5/Commutativity axiom.
